# Yii2 sending id to the url by clicking a div

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have a few divs with text content and that content is a object from database (it has post_id, user_id, content, title). How can i send the post_id to the url to render a view page with the whole content? I am working with Yii2. Guess i have to make it with javascript but do not even know how to start. Looked around for answer but still without result.

[these are the latest posts and when i click on one of them i have to render view action which will show the whole text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKjKX.png)

This is my actionView:

```
public function actionView()
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }
```

I have tried with jQuery .load() but guess ajax is not necessary for this case, or i just do not know how to use it as it seems :) Forgive me if the question is stupid but i am still learning.

Comment: How is the title related with question?

Comment: It is not .. my mistake! Will fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need PJAX to update a container according to GET parameters if you want to reload solely a part of the page without too much hassle.

Try wrapping your divs into `Pjax::begin();` and `Pjax::end();` and form the links using `echo Html::a($model->title, ['post/view', 'id' => $model->id])`

Sorry, wrote this from my phone, if this still doesnt solve your issue, you can write custom AJAX/PJAX for it or you could just go without it (loading the full page for each post).